# Solr: Properly qualifying PKs of records in delta import

Tags: sql, solr, primary-key, dataimporthandler, delta

There are some similar questions/answers on the Internet, but I still can't find a solution to [a problem related to the way Solr combines query statements when doing a delta import](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SOLR-2907) in combination with my current database structure (which I can't change).

### Problem

At first, I was getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: deltaQuery has no column to resolve to declared primary key pk='ID'` with the following data config:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="..."
            user="..."
            password="..."
            readOnly="true"
            batchSize="2000" 
            useCompression="true" />

    <document>
        <document>
            <entity name="job" pk="id"
                    query="SELECT
                            j.id,
                            j.employer_id,
                            j.title,
                            j.description,
                            j.created_on,
                            e.name AS employer,
                            s.address AS source_website_address
                            FROM jobs AS j
                            LEFT JOIN employers AS e ON e.employer_id = j.employer_id
                            LEFT JOIN source_websites AS s ON s.id = j.source_website_id"
                    deltaQuery="SELECT j.id FROM jobs j WHERE created_on > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
                    >
            <field column="ID" name="id" />
            <field column="EMPLOYER_ID" name="employer_id" />
            <field column="TITLE" name="title" />
            <field column="DESCRIPTION" name="description" />
            <field column="EMPLOYER" name="employer" />
            <field column="SOURCE_WEBSITE_ADDRESS" name="source_website_address" />
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

### Attempted solutions

#### Explicit entity primary key

I then tried [a possible solution by adding `pk="id"` to the `entity` element](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/how-to-perform-a-delta-import-when-related-table-is-updated-tp4032587p4032671.html), which then resulted in

```
Exception while processing: job document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT j.id, j.employer_id, j.title, j.description, j.created_on, e.name AS employer, s.address AS source_website_address FROM jobs AS j LEFT JOIN employers AS e ON e.employer_id = j.employer_id LEFT JOIN source_websites AS s ON s.id = j.source_website_id where id = 3355
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
    ...
```

#### Column aliasing

The column `id` is ambiguous because the table `jobs` as well as `source_websites` contains a column with that name. For that reason, I tried aliasing the primary-key columns to avoid the problem:

```
...
<entity name="job" pk="entity_id" query="SELECT j.id AS entity_id,
...
deltaQuery="SELECT j.id AS entity_id
...
```

However, by setting the columns as such, I now get

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT j.id AS entity_id, j.employer_id, j.title, j.description, j.created_on, e.name AS employer, s.address AS source_website_address FROM jobs AS j LEFT JOIN employers AS e ON e.employer_id = j.employer_id LEFT JOIN source_websites AS s ON s.id = j.source_website_id where entity_id = 199983
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'where clause'
...
```

#### Explicit delta import query

Finally, I tried explicitly defining the `deltaImportQuery` as

```
deltaImportQuery="SELECT
    j.id AS entity_id,
    j.employer_id,
    j.title,
    j.description,
    j.created_on,
    e.name AS employer,
    s.address AS source_website_address
    FROM jobs AS j
    LEFT JOIN employers AS e ON e.employer_id = j.employer_id
    LEFT JOIN source_websites AS s ON s.id = j.source_website_id
    WHERE id='${dataimporter.delta.entity_id}'"
```

However, this also results in `Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'where clause'`.

How do I suss Solr into creating an unambiguous select query while executing a delta import in this case?-- it seems I've tried everything except change the database schema, which I really, really do not want to do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Finally, I tried explicitly defining the deltaImportQuery as" - 
This query is incorrect, should be 
WHERE j.id='${dataimporter.delta.entity_id}'"
But you get strange error message for it, it looks like this query was never executed.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hitting this same problem with a very simple query that does not have field name collisions...  did this get solved?